# Problem with creating a midi file from scratch with C++. Crazy misalignment

Tags: c++, midi

So i have this code (dont judge the class instead of namespace and the namespace globals):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cmath>

namespace Global
{
    int m_BPM = 0;
}


class Midi
{
public:

    static void WriteVarLength(std::ofstream& file, int value)
    {
        int buffer[4];
        int i = 0;
        do {
            buffer[i++] = value & 0x7F;
            value >>= 7;
        } while (value > 0);

        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (j > 0) {
                buffer[j] |= 0x80;
            }
            file.put(static_cast<char>(buffer[j]));
        }
    }
    static void WriteHChunk(std::ofstream& file, int format, int nTracks, int division)
    {

        file.write("MThd",4);
        file.put(0x00);
        file.put(0x00);
        file.put(0x00);
        file.put(0x06);

        if (format == 0 || format == 1 || format == 2)
        {
            file.put(static_cast<char>(format >> 8));
            file.put(static_cast<char>(format));
        }

        else {
            MessageBox(
                    nullptr,
                    (LPCSTR)L"Invalid format number.",
                    (LPCSTR)L"MidiSaver",
                    MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK
            );
            exit(1);
        }

        file.put(static_cast<char>(nTracks >> 8));
        file.put(static_cast<char>(nTracks));

        file.put(static_cast<char>(division >> 8));
        file.put(static_cast<char>(division));
    }
    static std::streampos WriteTrackChunk(std::ofstream& file)
    {
        file.write("MTrk", 4);
        std::streampos pos = file.tellp();
        std::cout << "TrackLengthpos: " << pos << std::endl;
        file.put(0x00);
        file.put(0x00);
        file.put(0x00);
        file.put(0x00);
        return pos;
    }
    static void MetaEventBPM(std::ofstream& file, int m_BPM)
    {
        int tempo = 60000000 / m_BPM;
        file.put(static_cast<char>(0xFF));
        file.put(static_cast<char>(0x51));
        file.put(static_cast<char>(0x03));
        file.put(static_cast<char>(tempo >> 16));
        file.put(static_cast<char>(tempo >> 8));
        file.put(static_cast<char>(tempo));
    }
    static void MetaEndTrack(std::ofstream& file)
    {
        file.put(0x00);
        file.put(static_cast<char>(0xFF));
        file.put(0x2F);
        file.put(0x00);
    }
    static void DeltaEvent(std::ofstream& file, int delta)
    {

        int size = 1;
        for (int d = delta; d >= 128; d >>= 7) size++;

        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int shift = i * 7;
            int mask = (i == size - 1) ? 0x7F : 0xFF;
            file.put(static_cast<char>(((delta >> shift) & mask) | (i > 0 ? 0x80 : 0x00)));
        }
    }
    static void CalTHeaderLength(std::ofstream& file, std::streampos trackLengthPos) {
        std::streampos currentPos = file.tellp();
        file.seekp(0, std::ios::end);
        uint32_t trackLength = file.tellp() - trackLengthPos - 8;
        file.seekp(trackLengthPos);
        file.put(static_cast<char>(trackLength >> 24));
        file.put(static_cast<char>(trackLength >> 16));
        file.put(static_cast<char>(trackLength >> 8));
        file.put(static_cast<char>(trackLength));

        file.seekp(currentPos);
    }
    static void EventNoteOn(std::ofstream& file, int delta_time, int note, int velocity, int channel)
    {
        DeltaEvent(file, delta_time);

        int statusByte = 0x90 | (channel & 0x0F);

        file.put(static_cast<char>(statusByte));
        file.put(static_cast<char>(note));
        file.put(static_cast<char>(velocity));
    }
    static void EventNoteOff(std::ofstream& file, int delta_time, int note, int channel)
    {
        DeltaEvent(file, delta_time);

        int statusByte = 0x80 | (channel & 0x0F);

        file.put(static_cast<char>(statusByte));
        file.put(static_cast<char>(note));
        file.put(0x00);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Global::m_BPM = 170;
    std::string filename = "test.mid";
    std::ofstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);
    int format = 0;
    int nTracks = 1;
    int division = 96;
    Midi::WriteHChunk(file, format, nTracks, division);
    std::streampos trackLengthPos = Midi::WriteTrackChunk(file);
    std::cout << "trackLengthPos value: " << trackLengthPos << std::endl;
    Midi::MetaEventBPM(file, Global::m_BPM);
    Midi::EventNoteOn(file, 0, 60, 127, 0);
    Midi::EventNoteOff(file, 96, 60, 0);
    Midi::MetaEndTrack(file);
    Midi::CalTHeaderLength(file, trackLengthPos);

    file.close();
}
```

The code is supposed to generate a .mid file that creates a C5 note at the beginning of the file, and last a quarter note (96ticks)
However there is a weird issue i can't really fix for some reason
The C5 note is starting at the half of the 56th bar and also is misaligned. I don't know what can cause this, but the BPM is also for some reason wrong. The intended BPM is 170, but on FL Studio 20, it's 140 BPM and on OpenMPT, it's a default BPM value, 120.

Here's the hex of the .mid file generated by my program, if it helps:
0x4D, 0x54, 0x68, 0x64, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
0x00, 0x60, 0x4D, 0x54, 0x72, 0x6B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0E, 0xFF, 0x51,
0x03, 0x05, 0x62, 0xAD, 0x00, 0x90, 0x3C, 0x7F, 0x60, 0x80, 0x3C, 0x00,
0x00, 0xFF, 0x2F, 0x00

Thanks for any help.

I tried fixing it with this:
changed how delta-time is being written on NoteOn and NoteOff functions, 3 variations i think, one made it generate on 1976th bar of the file
changed the midi header function a bit

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of code? Is that a [mre]?

Comment: Have you tried to use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through your code line by line while monitoring variables and their values, to see what really happens? To help with this I suggest you split up all complex expressions into smaller parts, and save each result in variables. That will make it much easier to see if something goes wrong.

Comment: Apologies for using class instead of struct, it's a placeholder project to build up the functionality, and then to get it into the main project. I'll fix it soon.

Comment: Ive had to shift the format, without it the midi project is not opening.

Comment: Also yes i tried using a debugger, nothing crazy is going on. Everything seems to be fine.

Comment: Which MIDI file format specification are you following?

Comment: The 1.1 version from 1999. But i test it in modern programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the delta time for the 0xFF 0x51 BPM Meta command. Each event has a delta time, also the first command.

So add 0x00, if you want the note to be played immediately after the tempo event.
Adding the missing byte will change the length of the track from 14 bytes to 15 bytes.

Here's how the hex dump looks after the changes.

[image: Hex dump with changes]

The [010 Editor MIDI template](https://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/repository/templates/file_info.php?file=MIDI.bt&type=0&sort=) can now successfully parse the file. We can see that it contains 3 commands:

1. Meta Tempo command
2. Note on
3. Note off

[image: Parsed structure]

Comment: Meh, my MIDI player still doesn't like it and crashes...

Comment: Well, I should have saved the file, OMG. OpenMPT now plays it as well.

Comment: Thanks! Adding DeltaEvent function to the MetaEventBPM and passing it delta_time 0 made it work correctly.